# Hide component based on internal value

Tags: angular

In my component I'm calling a service. When the result is empty I want to set the component to 'hidden', because I don't want an empty bootstrap column.

```
<app-streams class="col-6" [hidden]="hideComponent"</app-streams>
```

I tried with setting an @output variable, but this didn't work.

```
@Output() hideComponent: boolean = false

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hideComponent = true
  }
```

P.S. The 'col-6' class has to be on this level, because nested inside the component template it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did You Try By putting *NgIf..?

Comment: @jesvinpalatty Yes, but the hideComponent variable does not exist on that level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is that you can refer to the child component variable value from the parent:

- Within child component do the following:

```
  hideComponent: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hideComponent = true;
  }
```

- Within parent you can do:

```
<app-streams
  #appstreams
  class="col-6"
  [style.display]="appstreams.hideComponent ? 'none' : 'block'"
></app-streams>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xghere?

Other way of solving this is to use `two way binding` to share variable `hideComponent` between parent and child as follows:

```
  @Input() hideComponent: boolean = false;
  @Output() hideComponentChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hideComponentChange.emit(true);
  }
```

Within the parent component you can do:

```
<app-streams
  class="col-6"
  [(hideComponent)]="hideComponent"
  *ngIf="!hideComponent"
></app-streams>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnr5fs?

Comment: Thank you!

But I have many dynamic components which are all <app-streams>. I left their inputs out because of clarity in the questions.

How to go about that?

Comment: @A.Nurb Then better go with using reference variables in first example #appstreams. So you'll have several components with different references like #appstreams1, #appstreams2 etc., and hide it like in first component. Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xghere for example

Answer (score 1):

You can set the visibility style attribute with [style binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-a-single-style):

```
<app-streams class="col-6" [style.visibility]="hideComponent? 'visible' : 'hidden'"</app-streams>
```

In component, on service subscription set `hideComponent = true` if result is empty `false` otherwise.

Comment: But the problem is that the variable is not know. I get this error: 

"Property 'hideComponent' does not exist on type 'ParentComponent'."

Comment: How you are calling service in your component?

Answer (score 1):

I would flip the logic and apply the ngIf to a div with the col class and have that house the component. That wayyou only get the div if its not hidden and the component doesn't have to worry about the presentation logic.

```
<div  class="col-6" *ngIf="!hideComponent">
    <app-streams></app-streams>
</div>
```

And if you cannot have that structure then you can `HostBind()` a class to the parent based on the variable in the child.